# What kinds of vegan sausage casings/skins are there?

Tags: veganism, substitutes, cooking

I would like to make my own vegan sausages at some point, but I have no clue about vegan casings/skins.

Do edible ones exist or are they all inedible? Are some much more processed than others? Do some contain a lot of artificial chemicals (i.e. reaction products, as opposed to just extracting what you want from a plant) than others?

Comment: This is a good question, and I am interested in the answer, but I make various vegan sausages with no casing at all...

Comment: @Zanna I think "no casing" is also a kind of casing and it would be appropriate to put it in an answer alongside other types. How do you make those sausages? Do you just form rolls from a kind of dough? BTW I found those: https://www.tongmaster.co.uk/sausage-casings-skins/veg-casing?product_id=480 but they don't even provide an ingredients list, so...

Comment: Oh! OK, I will share a couple of my recipes, just give me half an hour or so :)

Answer (score 4):

**Without casing**: these flour-based sausages are made by boiling, which gives them a fairly smooth skin of cooked starch similar to that of dumplings. They can be eaten like this, or fried later, or sliced and cooked in a stew...

I use these when the recipe calls for chorizo. I will update later with some other recipes when I have time to test and revise them, as I haven't made them for a while.

#### "Chorizo" style sausages

**Ingredients**

- 125g chickpea flour or rice flour
- 4 shallots or 1 onion very finely chopped or grated
- 4-6 sundried tomatoes, rinsed and very finely chopped
- 4-6 pre-soaked or rehydrated dried organic apricots, very finely chopped
- 1 tsp hot smoked paprika (optional)
- 2-3 tsp dried oregano
- Any other spices you like
- 3 tbsp ground flaxseed/other nut or seed powder
- 2 tbsp peanut butter or cashew butter or whatever nut butter you have
- 1 tbsp pumpkin seed oil or whatever oil you have
- 50ml (approx.) rice milk or your favourite mylk
- Vegetable stock, low salt

**Method**

1. Mix the dry ingredients in a large bowl
2. Add nut butter, oil and mylk and mix to make a dryish dough.
3. Squeeze and roll the dough into sausage shapes.
4. Make up a little vegetable stock (or use some you have left over from cooking another dish)
5. Boil the sausages gently in the stock (it should come about halfway up the sausages) for about 20 minutes, turning occasionally, and allow to cool.
6. Serve cold, or cook them again however you like.

Comment: Thanks. :) I just did some sausages inspired by your procedure: Take left over thick vegetable soup, make sure it's spicier than you would usually make soup. Mix in chickpea flour or whatever flour you have available (I didn't have enough chickpea flour and also used some soy and gluten flour) until it's a smooth non-sticky dough. Roll pieces of dough between hands and table to make rolls. Boil salt water, put them in and let them boil for 20 minutes. Already ate some, turned out ok. Currently frying some to see how that turns out. Probably I should have made them dryer.

Comment: Awesome idea! Thanks @Nobody

Answer (score 4):

You can use rice paper (spring rolls skins) to create a useable casing. It takes a little practice to get them really looking like sausages.

Make sure you get the vegan spring roll skins though because some of them do contain eggs.